# Обводка при выделении поля

Tags: html, css

Как убрать этот оранжевый бордер у хрома, при активации поля?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так точно должно сработать:

```
<style type="text/css">
input {outline:none}
</style>
```

Незабудте поставить галочку

Comment: Не работает

Comment: Попробуте второй вариант написанный мной...

Comment: <input name="nick" type="text" size="50" id="id_field">
                  <input name="password" type="password" size="50" id="id_field">
                  <input name="e-mail" type="text" size="50" id="id_field">

Comment: не работает 2 вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
input, textarea {
    outline: none;
} 
input:active, textarea:active {
    outline: none;
}
:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: :focus неправильно надо *:focus !

Answer (score 0):

```
input, textarea, input:active, textarea:active, *:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Если не поможет, попробуйте это:

```
* {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:active, :hover, :focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```